# How to compile program with windows sockets in linux?

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, gcc

I have a program written in **C** which uses the following libraries:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <winsock2.h>
#define socklen_t int
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

In **Windows**, in order to compile this program with **gcc**, you had to use `-lWs2_32` property.

How to compile it using *gcc in linux*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-lWs2_32` is a linker option to specify a library to link. The compiler does not use it.

For gcc under Linux there is no need to explicitly specify a library when using socket functions.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should statically link the executable and use MinGW. But it's just an assumption. Never tried it.

Comment: MinGW is a windows port of the Linux collection GCC :D

Answer (score -1):

-lWs2_32 is a linker option to specify a library to link. The compiler does not use it.

For gcc under Linux there is no need to explicitly specify a library when using socket functions.